# How to make control right aligned in table layout?

Tags: android

I am using table layout for my Android application. I have a row with two elements and I'd like second element was right aligned. Even if I use gravity="right", it still looks like left aligned. I can image that problem is that table cell doesn't get full width to the rest of the screen. However I do not see how I can control that.

Comment: Yes, it is. I do not have Android dev system available now, so will check the recommendation tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using layout_gravity="right" instead? And for filling the width for the screen, set the layout_width of the tablelayout to "fill_parent" and try using android:stretchColumns="*"

Comment: Tried these suggestions, but didn't help

Comment: did you do layout_gravity in the element's xml? and maybe try gravity as well.

Comment: I used for component. It looks like I should try relative layout to reach my goal, at least components are right aligned in examples.